# convert number to string

Tags: python, string, numbers

if I have a string s='ABCDEFJHI', and I slice it like this ['ABC','DEF','JHI'].
I have function encode(some calculation) which convert  the sliced string into numbers.

```
for example 'encode('ABC' ) gives 50 , encode('DEF') gives 33, encode('JHI') gives 10
```

['ABC','DEF','JHI'] gives [50,33,10].
I want to do the reverse case, decode(50) gives 'ABC' 
I have idea that when I encode sub-string , I create a library then I append  sub-string with its number like: ('ABC':50)(do the same for all the sub-strings), later in decode I will just extract the sub-string according to the number.
How can I do this in python?

Comment: Are these calculated according to an algorithm or just defined as pairs?

Comment: Be careful, if you are trying to work on compression or encryption you may come across clashes, for example, does ABC produce the same final number as BAC or CAB ? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's reversible, I suggest to store it in reverse format (50: 'ABC'). And also, imagine a situation where the given code has not encoded before.

```
encode_history = {}

def encode(str):
    """some calculations which lead to the code"""
    ... your calculations ...
    encode_history[code] = str
    return code


def decode(code):
    """function to convert a code to string"""
    if code in encode_history:
        return encode_history[code]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: OK.thanks.I apply this on '`s='AAGGTTCA` this gives `>>> encode_history
{1: 'AAG', 5: 'CA', 33: 'GTT'}` , but the result must be `encode_history
{1: 'AAG', 33: 'GTT', 5: 'CA'}`

Comment: Oh! I see! then dict won't work for you. 
You can define: `encode_history = []`, update it like: `encode_history.append((code, str))`, and then convert it to dict `codes = dict(encode_history)` in decode and work with this variable. So, it's not just encode-decode problem. right?

Answer (score 1):

In your encode function:

```
def encode(the_string):
    #do whatever encoding you're doing
    return (the_number,the_string)
```

and wherever you're using it, do:

```
d = dict()
for value in ["ABC","DEF","JHI"]:
    encoded,decoded = encode(value)
    d[encoded] = decoded
```

Define a function also like:

```
def decode(lookup_table,value):
    return lookup_table[value]
```

and use it like:

```
encoded_values = list()
for value in ["ABC","DEF","JHI"]:
    encoded,decoded = encode(value)
    d[encoded] = decoded
    encoded_values.append(encoded)

for value in encoded_values:
    print("{} | {}".format(value,decode(d,value)))

[OUT]
50 | ABC
33 | DEF
10 | JHI
```

That said -- why are you doing this, how are you doing this, and why aren't you using some sort of real encryption for it? If it's not two-way encryption, you should almost certainly NOT be storing the data anywhere, and if it IS two-way encryption, why not just decrypt it using the opposite algorithm you used to encrypt? Just keep that in mind.....

Comment: it is probably better to actually decode ... but given the info provided this is the only way to do it (that said if we saw how it was encoded it would be a different matter

Comment: @JoranBeasley Absolutely. I noted at the bottom of my answer that this is almost always the wrong implementation -- but given a bad question, I can only give a bad answer :P